# Why my KTM Duke 250 Speedometer turns on late after switching on the key?

Tags: speedometer, ignition-key, ktm

My KTM Duke 250 speedometer turns on late, sometime after 9-10 seconds after switching on the motorcycle with the key. Earlier the speedometer used to load/appear instantly when the motorcycle was switched on with the key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say without more diagnosing but one possibility:

The speedo could have an internal error and/or is failing its start up monitors preventing the main processors from booting properly the first few times it tries. This could cause you to see a delay in it coming on. I see this from time to time in automotive modules but I do not know moto stuff well sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it happens occasionally, anyway I am planning to take it to the service centre.